# How to select a single Name with known percentages?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a list of names with each having set probabilities. From this list i want a random name pulled, based on their percentages.
The list looks more or less like this:

```
A = 3.55
B = 5.1
C = 7.1
D = 7.3
E = 7.5
```

There are in total 20 names (here: instead of names i wrote letters) who add up to 100%.

I tried it with "random" and "for i in range" but failed quite fast and don't know hot to go on from here.
Any help would be fantastic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: random has a weights option for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said, you can use `random.choices()`:

```
import random

data = [3.55, 5.1, 7.1, 7.3, 7.5]

res = random.choices(data, weights=data, k=1) # Probably [7.5]
```

`random.choices()` determines the probability of each element as that element's weight over the sum of all weights. In this case, each element is its own weight. Thus, for instance, the probability of `7.5` being chosen is `7.5 / (3.55 + 5.1 + 7.1 + 7.3 + 7.5) = 0.24...`, whereas the probability of 3.55 being chosen is `0.11`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices.